# Tracking the amount of Ready work over time

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We're using Azure Devops Boards as our primary work tracking environment. For our agile planning process, we've got a backlog full of user stories for which we use tags to categorize PBIs. For instance, when a story is ready for refinement by the team, it's tagged with `Refinement`. As soon as refinement is done it's tagged with `Ready` to indicate we're going to take it up for sprint planning. Nothing out of the ordinary I'd say.

Now I was looking for a way to historically chart the count of user stories having these tags, but I can't seem to find a widget supporting that. The time-tracking widgets don't seem to take tags into account and with the query-type widgets you can search for tags but you get the current set of items, not the option to plot it historically.

Does anyone know whether this can be done in one way or the other?

Answer (score 1):

Some fields have a `was ever` such as `State`. Tags don't appear to support a `was ever` operator though, so you may have to use the REST API to search the audit data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0